# Visual Studio 2013 Find/Replace with Regex to exclude word

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to build a Regular Expression to find lines of code that match

```
Private Code As String
```

but not

```
Public Property Code As String
```

For now I have end with this

```
(dim|private|public|shared|) .+ As String(?=\r?$)
```

or

```
(dim|private|public|shared|)~(Property) .+ As String(?=\r?$)
```

With the first RegEx the property line of code still include. and with the second, absolutely nothing is founded

In other work, any string variable declaration, but not property/sub/function declaration or

Can anyone help on on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need this:

```
(Dim|Private|Public|Shared)\s\w+\sAs String.*
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/eO5oI4/2)

Comment: Thank for the reply, but i think that my question what not enough clear, I meen I search for Private [anyIdentifyer ] As String, but not Private Property [anyIdentifyer ] As String. In other work, any string variable declaration, but not property declaration. (I'll edit the main post)

Comment: @Hugo! yeah! Misunderstood!

Comment: Good thank! and what should I add to have only string declaration type?

Comment: (Dim|Private|Public|Shared)\s\w+\sAs String(?=\r?$)

Comment: @Hugo glad to have helped! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57333/discussion-between-hugo-and-amit-joki).